# How to convert this C# code to Visual basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates

Im not sure how to convert C# code with delegate into Visual basic code, can you help me?

```
List<XmlUser> matchingUsers = this.Store.Users.FindAll(delegate(XmlUser user) 
    {
        return user.Email.Equals(emailToMatch,
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
);
```

Comment: did you try to convert using these tools: http://amrelgarhy.com/blog/convert-vb-net-to-c-c-to-vb-net-tools/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim matchingUsers As List(Of XmlUser) = Me.Store.Users.FindAll( _
    Function(user As XmlUser) user.Email.Equals(emailToMatch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) _
)
```

Comment: The trick is that this requires at least Visual Studio 2008, since the emailToMatch variable is a closure.

Comment: closures were available from the first time they added anonymous delegates (i.e. .NET 2.0 VS2005)

Answer (score 3):

Compile the code. Get .Net Reflector:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

and Select Visual Basic for disassembling. Thats an easy way to convert between the 2 languages.

Comment: There's a closure transformation in there.  The reflected code will have significant differences from the original.

Comment: Yes for this code the reflected one wouldn't be that perfect, but the resulting code would work. I suggested to use reflector so he is able to solve such "conversion" problems in future without further asking.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [this converter](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/) with some success.  I'd start there.

Also, a quick Google search should give you some good results.